# Encrypting and decrypting String with special character

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to encrypt a Client' name (string format) storing it in a database and then retrieving it and decrypting it. As i need to avoid any third part libraries, i have used classes which are readily available with Java distribution.

The process was working fine, until I encountered a name with a special character (Ascii : 48910). This was geting displayed as a question mark(?). The encryption and descryption went fine, but after the decryption the special character was replaced with the question mark.

So i changed the Encoding format from *'UTF-8'* to *'ISO-8859-1'*. This solved the display problem, but still the special character gets replaced after decryption.

The code being used and the output is given below (i have removed the unnecessary code):

```
package crypt;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class SecretKeyEncryptionExample {

    private static final String FORMAT = "ISO-8859-1";
    public static final String DESEDE_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME = "DESede";

    private KeySpec ks;
    private SecretKeyFactory skf;
    private Cipher cipher;
    SecretKey key;

    public SecretKeyEncryptionExample() throws Exception {

        String myEncryptionKey = "4A144BEBF7E5E7B7DCF26491AE79C54C768C514CF1547D23";

        ks = new DESedeKeySpec(myEncryptionKey.getBytes(FORMAT));
        skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(DESEDE_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME);
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(DESEDE_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME);
        key = skf.generateSecret(ks);
    }

    public String encrypt(String unencryptedString) throws Exception {

        String encryptedString = null;
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] plainText = unencryptedString.getBytes(FORMAT);
        byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
        encryptedString = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(encryptedText);

        return encryptedString;
    }

    public String decrypt(String encryptedString)  throws Exception {

        String decryptedText = null;
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encryptedText = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(encryptedString);
        byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(encryptedText);
        decryptedText = new String(plainText);

        return decryptedText;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        SecretKeyEncryptionExample td = new SecretKeyEncryptionExample();

        String target = "Expendable" + getSpecialCharacter(49810) + "s Pte Ltd";

        String encrypted = td.encrypt(target);
        String decrypted = td.decrypt(encrypted);

        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, FORMAT);
        out.println("String To Encrypt: " + target);
        out.println("Encrypted String: " + encrypted);
        out.println("Decrypted String: " + decrypted);

    }

    public static String getSpecialCharacter(int code) {

        Charset charSet = Charset.forName(FORMAT);
        String specialCharacter = new String(new byte[] { (byte) code }, charSet);
        specialCharacter = String.format("%s", specialCharacter);

        return specialCharacter;
    }

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
String To Encrypt: Expendable’s Pte Ltd
Encrypted String: TAAJuF7KOmBZHBXFHsW0FB9YBwH7Tcif
Decrypted String: Expendable?s Pte Ltd
```

Please let know how the decryption can be attained, without getting the special character replaced.

Comment: If the problem is only "after decryption" can you simplify the example as it doesn't appear to have anything to do with encryption/decryption. BTW ASCII characters and `byte` values stop at 127 and ISO-8851-1 stops at 255 so it hard to work out what character you are talking about.

Comment: How does `"Expendable" + getSpecialCharacter(49810) + "s Pte Ltd";
` turn into `The Falcon’s Hangar Pte Ltd
`

Comment: Much of this doesn't make sense. There is no reason not to use UTF-8, the getSpecialCharacter method simply throws away the high bits of the character so that 49810 is really just 146. The problem though is that you are using the wrong String constructor. Use the String(byte[], Charset) constructor.

Comment: It is the character in the ISO-88589-1 charcter set with code 180. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent. Not able to type that in the editor.

Comment: There are quite allot of inconsistencies in the question.  I suggest you take a break and review your code e.g. is it 48910 or 49810 or 146? Is it ASCII (up to 127), ISO-8859-1 (up to 255) or UTF-8 (includes 49810)

Comment: @PeterLawrey output corrected.

Comment: @UnniKris I think we have the most likely answer in any case.  I get the impression you have been working on this for a long time and could do with clearing your head ;)

Comment: @GregS : You are correct, i was using the wrong character. Also after the decryption i shud hav used the String(byte[], Charset) constructor. Made myself dumb :S .

Comment: The encryption/decryption cycle will not cause the problem -- encryption can be used on pure binary data.  Almost certainly there is some error being made with regard to code pages on one end or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things which may be useful to know.

```
System.out.println((int) getSpecialCharacter(49810).charAt(0));
```

prints

```
146
```

This is the character you are actually creating here.

```
System.out.println("The Falcon" + (char) 146 + "s Hangar Pte Ltd");
```

prints

```
The Falcon’s Hangar Pte Ltd
```

I think the problem is that you get the bytes using the ISO-8859-1 character set with

```
byte[] plainText = unencryptedString.getBytes(FORMAT);
```

but when you turn it back into a String you use the system default.

```
decryptedText = new String(plainText);
```

I suspect this should be

```
decryptedText = new String(plainText, FORMAT); // use the same Charset
```

Comment: Yes the problem was with me using the wrong character. Somehow i came to the conclusion, that 49810 was the code correpsonding to the character. Actually it was (char)180. Need to have a break from coding to free up my mind :) .

Answer (score 2):

I think you should specify your encoding every time you go from a string to a byte array and back. In particular, this line:

```
decryptedText = new String(plainText);
```

should read:

```
decryptedText = new String(plainText, FORMAT);
```

Otherwise you rely on your environment's encoding, which in all likelihood differs from FORMAT and result in the special character being printed as "?".